# I don't understand how my calculations are being read as a str instead of an integer when the variables are valued with numbers

Tags: python

I am making a number guessing game for a project as a part of my intro to the coding class. I am trying to calculate the total earnings for the user, but I keep getting a type error and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```py
print("To begin the game pay two dollars")
print("You can collect your winnings when you stop playing")
import sys
count = 0
Jackpot_wins = 0
Reversed_digits = 0
Digit_WrongPlacement = 0
Digit_RightPlacement = 0
Digit_RightPlacement_two = 0
Digit_WrongPlacement_two = 0

JackpotValue = 100
Reversed_digitsValue = 10
Digit_RightPlacementValue = 10
Digit_WrongPlacementValue = 5
Cost_Per_Play = 2
Game_start = input("Would you like to play? enter 'y' for yes and 'n' for no: ")

if Game_start == "n":
    print("Thats ok, maybe next time")
    sys.exit()

while Game_start == "y":
    count = count + 1

    Money_Spent = count * Cost_Per_Play

    Player_Number = int(input("Enter a number 0-99: "))
    print(Player_Number)

    import random
    Hidden = random.randint(0,99)
    Reversed_digits = (str(Hidden)[::-1])
    print(Hidden)
    Jackpot = Hidden == Player_Number
    PN = int(Player_Number / 10)
    RN = int(Hidden / 10)
    PN1 = int(Player_Number % 10)
    RN1 = int(Hidden % 10)

    if Jackpot:
        print("Jackpot!!! You win 100 dollars!!!")
        Jackpot_wins = int(Jackpot_wins + 1)

    elif Player_Number == Reversed_digits:
        print("Right digits, wrong order!... You win 10 dollars!")
        Reversed_digits = int(Reversed_digits + 1)

    elif PN == RN:
        print("One digit correct, place correct. You win 10 dollars!")
        Digit_RightPlacement = int(Digit_RightPlacement + 1)

    elif RN1 == PN1:
        print("One digit correct, place correct. You win 10 dollars!")
        Digit_RightPlacement_two = int(Digit_RightPlacement_two + 1)

    elif PN1 == RN:
        print("One digit correct, place incorrect. You win 5 dollars!")
        Digit_WrongPlacement = int(Digit_WrongPlacement + 1)

    elif RN1 == PN:
        print("One digit correct, place incorrect. You win 5 dollars!")
        Digit_WrongPlacement_two = int(Digit_WrongPlacement_two + 1)

    else:
        print("Completely wrong")

    Game_start = input("To continue type 'y' to end type anything: ")

    JP_money = Jackpot_wins * JackpotValue
    RD_money = Reversed_digits * Reversed_digitsValue
    DRP_money = Digit_RightPlacement * Digit_RightPlacementValue
    DRP1_money = Digit_RightPlacement_two * Digit_RightPlacementValue
    DWP_money = Digit_WrongPlacement * Digit_WrongPlacementValue
    DWP1_money = Digit_WrongPlacement_two * Digit_WrongPlacementValue

    Winnings = JP_money + RD_money + DRP_money + DRP1_money + DWP_money + DWP1_money
    Total_earnings = Winnings - Money_Spent
if Game_start != "y":
            print("See you next time! You played ", count, "rounds.")
            print("you spent $ ", Money_Spent)
            print("Wow you won the Jackpot", Jackpot_wins, "times!")
            print("Your total earnings are", Total_earnings, "Congrats!")
```

I expected the code to keep tally of the wins and their varying values but I am either getting a type error or a value that is unbelievable like 72727171723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I tested the code, in your Winning calculation RD_Money is returning string number,

```
Winnings = JP_money + RD_money + DRP_money + DRP1_money + DWP_money + DWP1_money
```

For resolving this you can just convert it in the calculation like this

```
Winnings = JP_money + int(RD_money) + DRP_money + DRP1_money + DWP_money + DWP1_money
```

or you can do this

```
RD_money = int(Reversed_digits) * Reversed_digitsValue
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: This helped me with the type error, but I am still getting odd numbers as the total earnings. I get things like 60606060606 or a random repeating number I don't quite understand why

Comment: Use second way like  : RD_money = int(Reversed_digits) * Reversed_digitsValue